# How to fix apache ignite error "ignoredFailureTypes=[SYSTEM_WORKER_BLOCKED, SYSTEM_CRITICAL_OPERATION_TIMEOUT]"?

Tags: java, ignite

I'm setting up a in-memory cache store using apache ignite in my web application. Where I am starting the ignite node and storing some data in ignite cache store at the start of my application server. while doing so I m able to start ignite node but my app server got stuck in starting mode at the below line of code.

`igniteCache.getCache("some_string");`

1. Tried to increase failure timeout.
2. Tried again after increase the memory.

   ```
   IgniteConfiguration igniteConfig = new IgniteConfiguration();
       igniteConfig.setSystemWorkerBlockedTimeout(60 * 60 * 1000);
               StopNodeFailureHandler handler = new org.apache.ignite.failure.StopNodeFailureHandler();
               handler.setIgnoredFailureTypes(new HashSet());
               igniteConfig.setFailureHandler(handler);
               //implementing multiple cache stores
               List<CacheConfiguration> list = new ArrayList<CacheConfiguration>();
   CacheConfiguration<String, Object> cacheConfig0 = new CacheConfiguration<String, Object>(name);
   cacheConfig.setCacheMode(CacheMode.PARTITIONED);
   list.add(cacheConfig0);

   CacheConfiguration<String, Object> cacheConfig1 = new CacheConfiguration<String, Object>(name);
   cacheConfig.setCacheMode(CacheMode.PARTITIONED);
   list.add(cacheConfig1);
   //here starting the ignite node
   ignite = Ignition.start(igniteConfig);
   caches = ignite.getOrCreateCaches(list);
   ```

below are the exception i m getting while starting the server

```
*[15:08:12] Topology snapshot [ver=1, locNode=51a25b22, servers=1, clients=0, state=ACTIVE, CPUs=4, offheap=3.0GB, heap=2.5GB]
<Jul 27, 2019 3:08:35,634 PM IST> <Error> <org.apache.ignite.internal.util.typedef.G> <BEA-000000> <Blocked system-critical thread has been detected. This can lead to cluster-wide undefined behaviour [threadName=grid-timeout-worker, blockedFor=13s]> 
<Jul 27, 2019 3:08:36,625 PM IST> <Warning> <org.apache.ignite.internal.util.typedef.G> <BEA-000000> <Thread [name="grid-timeout-worker-#23", id=219, state=RUNNABLE, blockCnt=1, waitCnt=43]
> 
<Jul 27, 2019 3:08:49,975 PM IST> <Error> <> <BEA-000000> <Critical system error detected. Will be handled accordingly to configured handler [hnd=StopNodeOrHaltFailureHandler [tryStop=false, timeout=0, super=AbstractFailureHandler [ignoredFailureTypes=[SYSTEM_WORKER_BLOCKED, SYSTEM_CRITICAL_OPERATION_TIMEOUT]]], failureCtx=FailureContext [type=SYSTEM_WORKER_BLOCKED, err=class o.a.i.IgniteException: GridWorker [name=grid-timeout-worker, igniteInstanceName=null, finished=false, heartbeatTs=1564220302360]]]
class org.apache.ignite.IgniteException: GridWorker [name=grid-timeout-worker, igniteInstanceName=null, finished=false, heartbeatTs=1564220302360]
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.IgnitionEx$IgniteNamedInstance$2.apply(IgnitionEx.java:1831)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.IgnitionEx$IgniteNamedInstance$2.apply(IgnitionEx.java:1826)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.worker.WorkersRegistry.onIdle(WorkersRegistry.java:233)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.util.worker.GridWorker.onIdle(GridWorker.java:297)
    at org.apache.ignite.spi.discovery.tcp.ServerImpl$RingMessageWorker.lambda$new$0(ServerImpl.java:2663)*
```

Comment: How did you start the server node? Which discovery SPI are you using? My guess, based on what you've posted, is that the server and client can't communicate with each other. Firewalls or blocked multicast or...

Comment: Could you please post jstack output for your node hanging? Also please try to start with -DIGNITE_QUIET=false VM option and check the logs, I can see that there are some issues with discovery as in your case you are using multicast ip finder and other nodes in your network can clash with this one.

Comment: Another thing: what does `igniteCache.getCache("some_string");` do? It's not an Ignite function. Is it something custom?